# How do you pass Kinesis headers to Spring Cloud Stream functions in batch consumer mode?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function, spring-cloud-stream-binder

I am in the process of converting our existing stream processing code that currently uses the annotation-based programming model to use Spring Cloud Function instead. With consumer batch mode enabled, how can I pass the AWS Kinesis checkpointer to my `Consumer` so that only after the processor has successfully processed all of the messages in the batch do I perform the manual checkpoint operation? Using the annotation-based programming model, I am easily able to pass in the checkpointer using the `@Header` annotation. Will this approach still work as I have depicted in the following code snippet?

```
@Retryable(
      include = {ServerException.class},
      maxAttemptsExpression = "#{@myProperties.getRetry().getMaxAttempts()}",
      backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "#{@myProperties.getRetry().getDelay()}"))
  public Consumer<List<byte[]>> processStream(
      @Header(AwsHeaders.CHECKPOINTER) final IRecordProcessorCheckpointer checkpointer) {
    return m -> {
      try {
        myProcessor.process(m);
      } catch (final Exception e) {
        log.error("An error occurred processing the log messages", e);
        throw new ServerException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e);
      }
      checkpoint(checkpointer);
    };
  }
```

***UPDATE 1***

After updating the method signature of the `Consumer` to  `Message<List<byte[]>>`, my test fails with the following stack trace:

```
10:38:11.759 [main] ERROR o.s.c.s.c.ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter - Failed to convert payload [B@43ff0650
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `[B` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: (byte[])"{
  "kubernetes" : {
    "container_name" : "containername1",
    "pod_name" : "podname1"
  },
  "log" : "log1",
  "time" : "2021-12-03T22:16:32.752617927Z"
}"; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1741)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1515)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1420)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.PrimitiveArrayDeserializers.handleNonArray(PrimitiveArrayDeserializers.java:226)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.PrimitiveArrayDeserializers$ByteDeser.deserialize(PrimitiveArrayDeserializers.java:491)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.PrimitiveArrayDeserializers$ByteDeser.deserialize(PrimitiveArrayDeserializers.java:432)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3723)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.converter.ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter.lambda$convertParameterizedType$0(ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter.java:146)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.converter.ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter.convertParameterizedType(ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter.java:161)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.converter.ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter.convertFromInternal(ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:185)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.config.SmartCompositeMessageConverter.fromMessage(SmartCompositeMessageConverter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.convertInputMessageIfNecessary(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.convertInputIfNecessary(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:1068)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:707)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.apply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:562)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.messaging.TraceFunctionAroundWrapper.nonReactorStream(TraceFunctionAroundWrapper.java:336)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.messaging.TraceFunctionAroundWrapper.doApply(TraceFunctionAroundWrapper.java:108)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.FunctionAroundWrapper.apply(FunctionAroundWrapper.java:47)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$1.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:257)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.apply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:562)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.apply(PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionWrapper.apply(FunctionConfiguration.java:790)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1.handleMessageInternal(FunctionConfiguration.java:622)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:216)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.TestChannelBinder$IntegrationBinderInboundChannelAdapter.access$600(TestChannelBinder.java:220)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.TestChannelBinder$IntegrationBinderInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.processMessage(TestChannelBinder.java:298)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.TestChannelBinder$IntegrationBinderInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.lambda$accept$0(TestChannelBinder.java:278)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.TestChannelBinder$IntegrationBinderInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.accept(TestChannelBinder.java:277)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.TestChannelBinder$IntegrationBinderInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.accept(TestChannelBinder.java:261)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.TestChannelBinder$IntegrationMessageListeningContainer.handleMessage(TestChannelBinder.java:208)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:222)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.InputDestination.send(InputDestination.java:37)
    at com.example.MyProcessorIT.testSuccessfulMessageProcessing(MyProcessorIT.java:113)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

***UPDATE 2***

Here is my configuration I'm using that is not working:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        mystream-in-0:
          consumer:
            batch-mode: true
          destination: my-stream
          group: my-stream
      kinesis:
        binder:
          kpl-kcl-enabled: true
          headers:
            - __TypeId__
            - b3
        bindings:
          mystream-in-0:
            consumer:
              checkpoint-mode: manual
              listener-mode: batch
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The signature of your `Consumer` must be a `Message<List<byte[]>>`. so then you can call `message.getHeaders().get(AwsHeaders.CHECKPOINTER, IRecordProcessorCheckpointer.class)`

Comment: Please see my update to my original post. I tried your suggestion previously, but when I changed the method signature to include ```Message```, my test errored with the stack trace I posted. My understanding according to https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_batch_consumers is that I need to set ```spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<binding-name>.consumer.batch-mode``` to ```true``` to enable my consumer to process the messages as a batch. Is that not true? How to I enable batch processing with Kinesis as my binder?

Comment: I removed the ```spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<binding-name>.consumer.batch-mode``` property from my test configuration, and the test still fails with the same stack trace I posted in my update to my original post. I don't understand how to get your proposed solution working while preserving the ability to process messages as a batch.

Comment: See `listenerMode` for exactly Kinesis Binder: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc#kinesis-consumer-properties

Comment: Please see my Update 2 in my original post. I had that listenerMode value already set, and the test continues to fail with the same exception.

Comment: How does it work if you do like this `Consumer<Message<?>>` ?

Comment: Actually, that worked. But, that requires code like this now in my ```Consumer``` bean definition: ```return m -> myProcessor.process((Message<List<byte[]>>) m);``` Obviously, this is less than desirable and lacks clarity in the ```Consumer``` bean method definition. In addition, I haven't seen this issue/potential resolution discussed anywhere in the Spring Cloud Stream documentation, and I can't imagine this is a desired approach to go about accessing Spring Cloud Stream headers when processing messages in batch mode. Why does this work, and what is the long-term solution to this problem?

Comment: There is no other way to get access to headers from the `Consumer` unless it expects a `Message`. Why it doesn't work for `List<byte[]>` as generic arg of the message we need yet to investigate...

Comment: OK. Should this be opened as an issue in the  [Spring Cloud Stream project in GitHub](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream)?

Comment: Sounds like a plan! Let’s see first of all if there is one like this already